# Check if secure connection (HTTPS) on AuthorizationFilter in .Net6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

When writting an AuthorizationFilter in .Net Framework we could use:

```
AuthorizationContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection
```

This is not available anymore on .Net6.0, in it's equivalent `AuthorizationFilterContext`.

How can I check if the request is using HTTPS protocol (check if the connection "is secure"), inside an AuthorizationFilter in .Net6.0 ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HttpRequest.IsHttps Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.ishttps?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

```cs
AuthorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsHttps
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that.